# Javascript why array.slice() doesn't work when the first value is 0?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, I  don't understand why arr.slice doesn't work when the first value is 0, the returned array is empty:

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; arr[i]; i += size) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
```

Comment: What's this: `for (var i = 0; arr[i]; i += size) {`?

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: [Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You end direct the loop with the condition, which evaluates as `false`.

```
arr[i] -> arr[0] -> 0 -> false -> end for loop
```

Use the length of the array as check

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
```

Comment: But why it's evaluates as false ? I want to access in array case, why arr[0] doesn't work when it's value is 0 ?

Comment: Ok I understand, my bad ^^" arr[i] block my loop... I correct this to i < arr.length. thank you

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
  function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  var  newArr = [];

 for (var i = 0; typeof arr[i]!='undefined'; i += size) {
  newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
 }
  return newArr;
 }
chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `arr[i]` not `arr.slice`.

First Element of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]` is 0 and it is false.

Just use other conditions like `i < arr.length` in `for` statement.

Answer (score -1):

`for (var i = 0; arr[i]; i += size)` , `arr[0]` is `0`, means `false`, so the loop is never entered